# How to create own scope in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have some unterstanding problem with the scope in Laravel 5.4

I try to make a scope with a simple where like syntax.

```
 class Addresses extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Addresses";
    protected $primaryKey = 'adress';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function scopeSearchAdress($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        return $query->where('adress', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchTerm.'%s');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'adress');
    }

    public function contactPerson()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ContactPerson::class, 'adress');
    }

}
```

when i start the php artisan tinker and write this command:
`App\Address::searchAdress('1330')->get()` i get this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#695
     all: [],
   }
```

and i don't understand why i get an empty array. If i make a query in MSSQL i get the address with this adress=1330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is i guess with the string and int value

you are passing a string, work with this

```
App\Address::searchAdress(1330)->get();
```

change the scope query

```
return $query->where('adress', '=', $searchTerm);
```

Comment: i get the same result when i pass an int

Comment: this is working. But i don't understand why the LIKE Operator and wildcards are not working.

Comment: because thats a primary key, you can change it to some other columns and do LIKE and check, it will work

Comment: it's working. But when i search after a city and the city is for example a german city like Düsseldorf i get an error `SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred translating string for input param 1 to UCS-2`

Comment: that you need to check with the unicode and all. you might need to convert the input to utf-8 and so.